# Understanding a proof of the local version of nakayama's lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $A$ module. If $x_1,...,x_n$ are in $M$ such that their image forms a basis of $M/\mathfrak{m}M$, then the $x_i$'s generate $M$.

I am trying to understand this proof: First we let $N$ be the submodule of $M$ generated by the $x_i$'s. By assumption, the image of $N$ in the quotient map $\pi$ from $M$ to $M/\mathfrak{m}M$ is all of $M/\mathfrak{m}M$. Hence $\pi^{-1}(\pi(N))=M$.

My notes say that we also have $\pi^{-1}(\pi(N))=N+\mathfrak{m}M$ since it is the smallest submodule of $M$ generated by $N$ and $\mathfrak{m}M$. I don't understand this equality. Is it a definition on or some consequence of inverse image of module homomorphism?

I also do not understand this part. Since $N+\mathfrak{m}M=M$, and since $A$ is local, we have $\mathfrak{m}\subset \operatorname{Jac}(A)$ and hence $N=M$. I know that if $A$ is local then its maximal ideal is in the Jacobson radical but why does this give that $\mathfrak{m}M=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your first question: If $f:X \to Y$ is a module homomorphism and $X' \subset X$ is a submodule, then $f^{-1}(f(X'))=X'+\mathrm{ker}(f)$
Let's prove this. Clearly $X' \subset f^{-1}(f(X'))$ and $\mathrm{ker}(f) \subset f^{-1}(f(X'))$, so $X'+\mathrm{ker}(f) \subset f^{-1}(f(X'))$.
For the other inclusion, let $v \in f^{-1}(f(X'))$. This means that $f(v) \in f(X')$, so we can find somet $v' \in X'$ with $f(v)=f(v')$. This means that $v-v' \in \ker(f)$, as $f(v-v')=f(v)-f(v')=0$. Thus we see that $v=v'+(v-v') \in X' + \mathrm{ker}(f)$.
To apply this to the problem, note that the kernel of the projection $\pi:M \to M/\mathfrak{m}M$ is $\mathfrak{m}M$, so $\pi^{-1}(\pi(N))=N+\mathfrak{m}M$

About the second question: If $M$ is a finitely generated $A$-module over a ring $A$ with Jacobson radical $J(A)$ with a submodule $N \subset M$ such that $M=N+J(A)M$, then $M=N$

The proof goes like this: consider $M/N$, then by assumption $J(A)(M/N)= (N+J(A)M)/N=M/N$, thus by Nakayama's lemma we have $M/N=0$. This implies $N=M$